# Adobe XD to flutter all widgets not exporting

Tags: flutter, adobe, adobe-xd

Recently, I downloaded a UI Kit. I am trying to convert this UI kit into flutter via xd to flutter plugin.
I have downloaded the plugin and trying to export all the widgets. I have given the proper path but it is not exporting at all, even it is not showing any error or something.
[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

It's the 'prototype interactions' check box you have selected in settings. I just removed all the check boxes to get it working. That should at least get you moving. Just had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

first select the path folder you want to export the dart file then click export all widgets you can get all widgets dart files